# 3D geometry converting equation of line from symmetric form to general form(as intersection of 2 planes)

Tags: geometry, 3d

I wanted to find out an easy way to convert the equation of line in 3d from symmetric to general form. I find it difficult to express a line (3-d) as an intersection of 2 planes given the equation of line of intersection.
(it would be great if one shares a simple example along with explanation).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What are the things you have tried already and why are you interested in this problem? It would be nice if you could add an explanation what you mean by symmetric form of a line.

Comment: Do you know how to compute a basis for the null space of a matrix or how to find vectors that are perpendicular to a given vector?